# Flow execution/logical context across async calls

Tags: java, android

Is there a mechanism in Android (Java) to retain logical context, similar to .NET's [`ExecutionContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext(v=vs.110).aspx)? By logical context I mean information that once retained, is later accessible across the entire *logical* thread of execution, meaning it will survive async calls. For example:

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print(LogicalContext.get("foo")); //should print "bar" 
    }
};

LogicalContext.set("foo", "bar");
handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

To clarify, I know about closures. What I need however is an automatic mechanism that will not require me to capture the context I want to pass every time. To further clarify, a mere static field won't do either, as I would want different logical threads of execution to have different contexts (which would start when I call `LogicalContext.set` and flow [essentially by copying] through any async call made from then on).

In C# it would look like this:

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("foo", "bar");
await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("foo")));
```

If that's impossible, I would settle for a special case of this mechanism - determine whether the current logical flow/thread of execution originated from an `IntentService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InheritableThreadLocal<T>`, which is similar to .NET's `AsyncLocal<T>`:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final InheritableThreadLocal<String> foo = new InheritableThreadLocal<String>();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         System.out.print(foo.get()); // prints "Bar"
    }
};

foo.set("Bar");
handler.postDelayed(r, 1);
```

Comment: It's important to note though that it's not completely equivalent to .NET's execution context. It only applies when a thread is being *created*, so when delegating work to an existing thread (e.g. the main / UI looper) the context won't flow. This is in contrast to .NET's execution context, where `CallContext.LogicalSetData` would flow even when using something like  `SynchronizationContext.Post` (which in UI frameworks such as WPF typically posts the delegate to an existing [UI] thread).